# Error while passing startDate and endDate as parameters in SQL query through java

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am getting startDate and endDate as start date of previous month and end date of previous month from current date. And I am trying to use these fields in my SQL query in java program.

My code looks like this:

```
public class DocumentUploads extends BaseSqlQuery<DocumentUploadDetails> {


    static Date currentDate = new Date();
    static Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

    static String startDate ;
    static String endDate; 

    static{
    c.set(currentDate.getYear()+1900,currentDate.getMonth() -1, c.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    startDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyy").format(c.getTime());

    c.set(currentDate.getYear()+1900,currentDate.getMonth() -1, c.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    endDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyy").format(c.getTime());

    }

    @Override
    public String getQuery() {

         return QUERY;
    }

    @Override
    public void declareParameters() {
    }

    @Override
    public DocumentUploadDetails mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int rowNum)
        throws SQLException {
        DocumentUploadDetails appointment = new DocumentUploadDetails();
        appointment.setId(resultSet.getLong("ID"));
        appointment.setAppNum(resultSet.getLong("APP_NUM"));
        appointment.setCaseNum(resultSet.getString("CASE_NUM"));
        appointment.setDocType(resultSet.getString("DOC_TYPE"));
        appointment.setSource(resultSet.getString("SOURCE"));
        appointment.setUploadDate(resultSet.getDate("UPLOAD_DT"));
        return appointment;
    }

    private static final String QUERY ="SELECT * FROM CASE_UPLOADS WHERE  UPLOAD_DT >=" + startDate + "AND UPLOAD_DT <=" + endDate;

}
```

After executing my code I am getting following error:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT * FROM CASE_UPLOADS WHERE UPLOAD_DT >=01/05/15AND UPLOAD_DT <=31/05/15]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER

at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:99)


at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:660)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:695)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:722)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:772)
at org.springframework.jdbc.object.SqlQuery.execute(SqlQuery.java:111)
at org.springframework.jdbc.object.SqlQuery.execute(SqlQuery.java:121)
at org.springframework.jdbc.object.SqlQuery.execute(SqlQuery.java:136)
at com.leader.ladpss.document.data.controller.QueryController.getCaseUploadsDetails(QueryController.java:15)
at com.leader.ladpss.document.Application.main(Application.java:20)
```

I tried to convert data types of startDate and endDate to Date and removing use of SimpleDateFormat function. But still its not working.

Please tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: if you read the exception really well u can find the problem

Comment: Try this but I think there are better ways of doing this private static final String QUERY ="SELECT * FROM CASE_UPLOADS WHERE  UPLOAD_DT >= \"" + startDate + "\" AND UPLOAD_DT <= \"" + endDate + "\"";

Comment: Where you call the statement. What is the content of QUERY ...?

Comment: Down vote for what? Atleast tell me what I asked wrong in the question.

Comment: @CodeCat  I gone through exception and even I am not sure how the string is getting converted into number

Comment: I believe you just need to put the dates in a string, see my comment above

Comment: @slarge No...Thats too not working

Comment: @Rushikesh do you get the same error or a different one?

Comment: @slarge If i give "\'" then its giving error: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string and if i give "\"" then its giving ORA-00904: "2015-05-31": invalid identifier error.

Comment: @Rushikesh Just my bad typing in this comment window I think. Try String QUERY ="SELECT * FROM CASE_UPLOADS WHERE UPLOAD_DT >= \"" + startDate + "\" AND UPLOAD_DT <= \"" + endDate + "\""; and see what error you get

Comment: @slarge ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

Comment: @Rushikesh I think you need TO_DATE, sorry Oracle isn't my thing :-). Try this tring QUERY ="SELECT * FROM CASE_UPLOADS WHERE UPLOAD_DT >= to_date('" + startDate + "', 'dd/MM/yyy') AND UPLOAD_DT <= to_date('" + endDate + "', 'dd/MM/yyy')";

Comment: @slarge Thanks a lot. Now its working using TO_DATE() function. Please post ur answer with explanation. I will accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the Oracle `TO_DATE` function to format the date correctly.

```
private static final String QUERY = "SELECT * 
            FROM CASE_UPLOADS 
            WHERE UPLOAD_DT >= to_date('" + startDate + "', 'dd/MM/yyy')
            AND UPLOAD_DT <= to_date('" + endDate + "', 'dd/MM/yyy')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..

```
private static final String QUERY ="SELECT * FROM CASE_UPLOADS WHERE  UPLOAD_DT >='" + startDate + "' AND UPLOAD_DT <='" + endDate +"'";
```

there need a space before AND

Comment: no. after adding space also I am getting same error

Comment: try changing the startDate and endDate type from String to Date

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its because of your date format. The SQL date format looks like this:

DATE - format YYYY-MM-DD

you format your date like this: SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyy")